# SharePoint Audit Entries

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

In my application i process audit logs to get the items that have been changed. Once audit entry is got, then i run SPSiteDataQuery to be able to get ListId of particular item, as SPAuditEntry does not expose that property.

This works ok, however for big number of audit entries it works very slow,e.g. 10K audit logs take around 12 mins to run all this data queries.

I am wondering is there a way to extend out of box audit log writing, so right in the process of logging it writes also ListId in the log?

Thanks,

Hrayr

Comment: for my understanding; what items are you changing?

Comment: Document library items and custom list items

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe that the auditing is extendable. But the audit entry does contain information about the list the audit occurred in. Isnt the property `SPAuditEntry.DocLocation` sufficient?

Comment: Ok, so what i am aware of, you can get information about listid, web id from audit entry in one of the following ways.  Use SPSiteDataQuery and query the itemid which comes in AuditEntry(this works, however as i mentioned performance is too low ), and second is DocLocation, so you can open the site/web/list and get that. This works pretty fast, but in case of edit audit entries, this doclocation contains info before actual edit has been done, and not after that, so if for example you change filename in library from Test.doc to Test1.doc, the doclocation will still point you to TestDoc.